# regex with OR condition not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, regex, string

I'm trying this simple regex in angularjs and it is not working to validate the input string. The string should begin with 3 alphabets followed by 7 digit any number.

Example :

```
ABC-1234567 or XYZ-1234567
```

The regex expresion me using is -

```
var validRegex = /^[ABC| XYZ]-[0-9]{7}$/;
```

this is not working , dont know where I'm wrong.

thanks

Comment: You need `()`, not `[]` around `ABC|XYZ`

Comment: Should also remove the space after the `|`, and you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, less wordy

Comment: And if you want **any** three alphabetic characters, you should replace `[ABC|XYZ]` with `[A-Za-z]{3}`